# Ktor Multiplatform Bearer Token Refresh leads to "mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal.Ref"

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I'm trying to get the Ktor client to refresh a Bearer token in a Kotlin Multiplatform project.

There is an example [here](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/main/codeSnippets/snippets/client-auth-oauth-google/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt) how it's supposed to work.

My code for the http client config looks actually quite similar - besides the different requests for getting and refreshing a token:

```
...
install(Auth) {
    lateinit var tokenInfo: TokenInfo
    var refreshTokenInfo: TokenInfo

    bearer {
        loadTokens {
            val url = "https://${environment.host}:${environment.port}/oauth/login"
            tokenInfo = tokenClient.post<TokenInfo>(url) {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                body = buildJsonObject {
                    put("username", "blah")
                    put("password", "blub")
                }
            }
            BearerTokens(
                accessToken = tokenInfo.data.access_token,
                refreshToken = tokenInfo.data.refresh_token
            )
        }
        refreshTokens {
            val url = "https://${environment.host}:${environment.port}/oauth/refresh"
            refreshTokenInfo = tokenClient.get<TokenInfo>(url) {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, tokenInfo.data.refresh_token)
            }
            BearerTokens(
                accessToken = refreshTokenInfo.data.access_token,
                refreshToken = refreshTokenInfo.data.access_token
            )
        }
    }
}
```

But this leads to `mutation attempt of frozen kotlin.native.internal.Ref`.
Seems it doesn't like the `lateinit var tokenInfo: TokenInfo`.

This only happens on iOS. Android works.

(Btw I switched to the [new memory model](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/try-the-new-kotlin-native-memory-manager-development-preview/). But in this case it does not seem to matter, it's the same error.)

Comment: I had a very similar issue in iOS and I have already posted a question and answer here :- https://stackoverflow.com/q/69800289/12768366

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652101/3585796). The new memory model should fix this, but it hasn't been released yet, so it probably doesn't cover this case so far.

Comment: Here is the ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1628 about the `InvalidMutabilityException` in general.

Comment: Here is the similar issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3350.

Answer (score 1):

(A) solution (for me) was to use what @Philip Dukhov pointed me to: [Atomics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-concurrent-mutability.html#atomics) (I guess I should have really read and not just skim it in the first place.)

So I added a wrapper to the TokenInfo using an [AtomicReference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-concurrent-mutability.html#atomicreference):

```
object AtomicTokenInfo {
    val ref = AtomicReference(TokenInfo(Data(""), listOf()).freeze())

    fun storeNewValue(tokenInfo: TokenInfo) {
         ref.value = TokenInfo(tokenInfo.data, listOf()).freeze()
    }
}
```

And then used it in my code like:

```
    var tokenInfo = AtomicTokenInfo

    ...

    val url = "https://${environment.host}:${environment.port}/oauth/refresh"
    tokenInfo.storeNewValue(
         tokenClient.get<TokenInfo>(url) {
             contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
             header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, tokenInfo.ref.value.data.access_token)
         }
    )
```

Thanks a ton for your comments & help @WhiteSpidy, @Philip Dukhov, @Aleksei Tirman